# React Native loading screen (conditional render)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, reactjs

I am trying to render a view in a React Native Android app when a HTTP call has completed.

My render method:

```
render: function() {
    if (this.state.obj.name) {
        return this.renderPage();
    } else {
        return (<Loading />);
    }
}
```

< Loading /> contains simple View and Text elements which display "Loading".

I call the network request in componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;

    SomeService.getObjById(1).then(function(data) {

        var obj = JSON.parse(data._bodyText);

        self.setState({
            obj: obj
        });
    });
},
```

However, when I update the state and instantiate 'obj' (which now has a name prop) render is recalled, it returns render page but the view does not update.

My renderPage method works when it is light like:

```
renderPage: function() {
    return (
        <View><Text>Hello</Text></View>
    )
}
```

But when it has more than say 6 lines of code it seems it doesn't update.

Any idea why event though the conditional returns different components when the call is finished, the actual view does not update?

Comment: I've set up your question with some mock data at https://rnplay.org/apps/nqcBQA . Can you possibly replicate the issue there? It seems to be returning just fine with a few lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go

Comment: I implemented what you did on the android side and it doesnt work... https://rnplay.org/apps/LTw07A any idea why? new to RNPlay

Comment: If you're talking about the UIManager error, that has something to do with their end, none of my apps are working right now on their android simulator.

Comment: Ah, I should've stated it's an Android app, I will update, thanks though.

Comment: That particular functionality should not matter based on platform.

Comment: It shouldn't, however you say it works on iOS and I cant replicate it working in Android. FWIW, I cant load the app you made on RNPlay, it crashes. Does it load for you?

Comment: It just works on the iOS version

Comment: I think the Android simulator is down on their site.

Comment: Seems to be that way

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by making the request before the change of view.

This still didnt work but I added a setTimout(function(){}, 0) around the navigator.push() and this worked, as it pushed the 'push' to the end of the call stack.

Not amazing, but works